# How to set code formatting to allow end-of-line comments?

Tags: c#, coding-style, xamarin-studio

The C# code formatting in Xamarin Studio (i.e. when hitting Ctrl-I to format the document) puts end of line comments onto a new line. I can't find any way to change this in the C# code formatting policy settings. How to change this to preserve end of line comments on the same line?

For example, take this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    int bar; // comment
}
```

If I hit Ctrl-I (or alternately click Edit > Format > Format Document from the menu, or select the code and click Edit > Format > Format Selection from the menu), the code is reformatted as:

```
public class Foo
{
    int bar; 
    // comment
}
```

I'm using <s>v4.2.2 build 2</s> **v4.3 build 52** on OS X.

Note: it seems this is a [bug](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9985/how-to-set-c-code-formatting-to-allow-end-of-line-comments#latest). So my question really is -- has anyone who has also encountered this come up with a fix or workaround and if so what is it?

Comment: Just to make sure: I assume you custom bound `Ctrl+I` to `Edit | Format | Format Document`? In latest version of Xamarin Studio I'm not reproducing your problem -- can you provide a line of code where this fails for you?

Comment: @BradRem - actually the Ctrl-I binding was there already (I'm on OS X v4.2.2 build 2). It happens for any line with a "// comment" at the end. Added example.

Comment: From what it sounds from the bug report you provided, they have to fix it on their end and, more importantly, they don't know it's still broke. The fix is to submit a bug report.

Comment: An FYI, v4.2.2 running on Win7 doesn't suffer this problem. The comment remains after the LOC terminator even after a Ctrl+I/Format Document.

Comment: @Ghopper21 Been awhile since I heard from you? Have you sorted the problem now?

Comment: @AshleyMedway - Nope. Haven't had a chance to reinstall on another account, much less reinstall OS X. Meanwhile, the upvotes on this question suggest to me that it's not just me... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been acknowledged as a bug by Xamarin. See this [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21404). In that report, Xamarin says it's replacing its entire formatting engine as of mid-2014, with the hope of having it in place by "next year." Xamarin further suggests avoiding the problem by turning off auto-formatting on save, suggesting there is no official fix or workaround at this time other than avoiding the issue.

Answer (score 5):

<s>I don't think there is a real answer to this question, as you have said its a bug in the version you are using.</s>
*UPDATE*: We have discovered that this is not a bug in the software. As it affects all versions the OP updates to, most likely there is some setting or extension affecting the outcome.

A work around although you may not be to happy with it would be to place you comments above the line in question. This is a perfectly acceptable way of code-commenting.

```
public class Foo
{
   // comment
   int bar;   
}
```

**Using version 4.3**
*Pre <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>*
[image: Unformatted]

*Post <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>*
[image: Formatted]

As a final note you may want to view your code formatting preferences found here:
[image: Settings]

**UPDATE 1**
You could try resetting all your preferences by deleting everything in the following folders, see [here](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/User_Profiles).
<s>I will add that I haven't tried this so could break your installation.</s>
Just tested and this **doesn't** break Xamarin Studio and does reset all preferences.

- `~/Library/Preferences/XamarinStudio-4.0/`
- `~/Library/XamarinStudio-4.0/`

**UPDATE 2**
The only last thing you can try as we have found out this isn't a bug in the software but something on your computer. Is to do a full removal of Xamarin Studio. I recommend using [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) as it will search for any related files and remove them.
Onces it has fully uninstalled, then reinstall Xamarin Studio.

**UPDATE 3**
Last solution, try creating a new user account. Run Xamarin Studio under that account to see if the problem persist. If it does the only thing left to do is a fresh install of OS X and reinstall Xamarin Studio first. The problem should be gone now... reinstall all other applications checking that nothing has broken Xamarin Studio after each install.

Comment: Thanks - and you are talking about OS X versions? You screen shot is certainly OS X.

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.3.0 build 52. (Didn't see it before as I wasn't on the Alpha upgrade channel.) But I still have the problem. Strange.

Comment: @Ghopper21 have you tried changing the setting shown in the last screenshot? Yes I'm on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: @Ghopper21 you could try disabling any extensions you have installed? I think given the comments this might just be an issue for you... Is there anything you can think of that might have started this: extensions, adding, software install?

Comment: Yes, have been through the Code Formatting settings several times to see if there was something relevant there. Will play around with extensions -- good idea.

Comment: @Ghopper21 I have put an update at the end of my answer details where Xamarin Studio stores its preferences should you wish to try and remove the files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44524/discussion-between-ashley-medway-and-ghopper21)

Comment: Sadly neither disabling various add-ons nor deleting all preference files fixes this...

Comment: @Ghopper21 Lets try to continue this in chat? Try a fresh install using a full remover app?

Comment: Just did AppCleaner removal with clean download and install and... problem persists. :-(

Comment: @Ghopper21 The only other thing I can suggest, if its not language settings? Is to do a fresh install of OS X theres no reason as to why this is happening to you? First before you do that, setup a new user account and see if that account has the same problem.